# Avoiding XSLTForms main form data model replacement

Tags: xsltforms

I'm using subforms (SO useful!) and I'm having a problem: I need certain subforms load some JS behaviour and some "xf:setdata" actions, so in the header of these subforms I included something like this:

```
<head>
    <xf:model xmlns="" id="aux">
        <xf:load ev:event="xforms-subform-ready" resource="javascript: loadMagicMenu('#mainMenu');"/>
    </xf:model>
</head>
```

The problem is doing this the main data model (included in the main form) is lost, so I can't reference it by adding controls. E.g. This is not working:

```
<xf:group model="magic-main-model">
    <xf:input ref="instance('wizzard')/@name" class="xforms-value">
        <xf:label>Name:</xf:label>
    </xf:input> 
</xf:group>
```

But if I delete the subform data model, it does work. And if the following subform has no model defined, it is possible to access to the main model.

So I tryed to put the "on load" actions in other places (in the same subform), but it didn't work.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to copy the main data model definition in the subform. I checked if another cloned model is made, but no, everything went ok!